# C# Raw input redirect input

Tags: c#, raw-input

I've been searching for a solution on this for a long time.. and I've tried several threads with no luck..

My problem is that i have another keyboard ( a barcode scanner ) and i want to catch that input, and redirect it to my own program so let's say that i have notepad open, and focused, when i scan a barcode all the input will go to notepad, here comes the question.. is it possible for me to redirect all the input from the scanner to my own program? so that when i have notepad open and focused and i scan a barcode i can identify the keyboard with the Vendor ID i can redirect the input to my own program and notepad would still be empty..

My code is based on this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

but i just want to redirect the input.

Comment: have you considered/tried making your application "always in front" from the task manager?

Comment: would that solve the problem? well.. i mean, should i make an "invisibleness" always in front application then?

Comment: no i just suggested giving it a try. the application will always be in front, so it will take the input to itself. not so reliable, but an easy approach i would say.

Answer (score 0):

This program did the job: http://nate.dynalias.net/dev/keyboardredirector.rails works like a charm!